# Calling a member constructor in class definition with a deleted copy constructor and initializer list overload

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo(const Foo&) = delete;
    Foo(int a, int b);
    Foo(std::initializer_list<int>);    
};

struct Bar
{
    Foo f = Foo(1, 2);
    // Foo f = {1, 2} - calls the initializer_list overload
};
```

How to initialize Foo with two ints if the copy constructor is deleted?

Comment: @rozina use the ctor-initializer list

Comment: @M.M Strange that there is no syntax to call a constructor directly in class definition though.

Comment: I you can change `Foo`, I suggest to add tag for `Foo(some_tag_t, int a, int b);`, and problem solved.

Comment: @rozina this is a fairly rare situation (non-copyable non-movable class, and having initializer_list constructor behave differently to int a, int b)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order for that initialization to work, the type in question has to be [MoveConstructible](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/MoveConstructible)<sup>*</sup>. In your particular case, providing a move constructor would satisfy this requirement:

```
Foo(Foo&&) = default;
```

If this is not an option, you could initialize the member in a default constructor, and use it as a delegating constructor in other constructors.

```
struct Bar
{
    Bar() : f(1, 2) {}
    Bar(const FooBar&) : Bar() {}
    Bar(double x) : Bar() {}
    Foo f;
};
```

---

<sup>* This does not mean a copy will be made. `T t = T()` is an easy candidate for copy elision. However, a viable constructor must be accessible.</sup>

Comment: If move constructor is provided, does that mean it is also called? I see no reason for a move here, a call to constructor is all that is needed.

Comment: @rozina It is extremely unlikely (easy copy elision) but a viable constructor has to be accessible.

Comment: Thanks again. I find it interesting that there is no syntax to call a constructor directly in a class definition. Seems like an oversight of the language.

Comment: @rozina Right. And it all stems from the "parse everything that can be as a function" from C, plus the rules about `std_initializer_list` constructors taking precedence. Basically, you should avoid writing classes where this could be an issue.

Comment: @T.C. Thanks, I added a link to the cppreference for `MoveConstructible`. P0125 looks good. I hope it goes in at some point.

Comment: <pedantic>MoveConstructible is actually stronger than needed (it has semantic requirements that aren't needed for the code to compile).</pedantic>

Comment: @T.C. Can you elaborate? I can't really see it (except for the RHS rvalue expression being of type T, which it is in this example anyway)

Comment: "The value of u is equivalent to the value of rv before the initialization" doesn't have to hold for the code to compile, though it'd be silly not to do it anyway. :)

Comment: @T.C. Ah of course. Although I said "work", which could be taken to imply the more restrictive semantics :-)